# how to draw perfect line in python using opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to draw perfect line using mouse event by clicking and dragging the mouse.
problem is multiple lines are getting printed while drawing.

here is the code which I have been testing.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

drawing = False
x1,y1 = -1,-1

def draw_shape(event,x,y,flag,parm):
    global x1,y1,drawing

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        #print('Cliked',x,y)
        #print('('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
        #cv2.line(img1,(x,y),(x,y),(0,0,255),2)
        drawing = True
        x1,y1 = x,y
        cv2.line(img1,(x1,y1),(x,y),(0,0,255),2)


    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        #drawing = False
        #print('('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
        if drawing == True:
            #print('('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
            a = x
            b = y
            if a != x & b != y:
                cv2.line(img1,(x1,y1),(x,y),(0,0,255),2)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        #print('Released',x,y)
        cv2.line(img1,(x1,y1),(x,y),(0,0,255),2)



img1 = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('Draw')
cv2.setMouseCallback('Draw',draw_shape)


while(True):
    cv2.imshow('Draw',img1)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw on the backed image when moving maybe a choice:

[image]

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2018/05/14 19:17:13
import cv2
import numpy as np

drawing = False
x2,y2 = -1,-1

def draw_shape(event,x,y,flag,parm):
    global x2,y2,drawing, img, img2

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        print('Cliked: ', (x,y))
        drawing = True
        img2 = img.copy()
        x2,y2 = x,y
        cv2.line(img,(x2,y2),(x,y),(0,0,255),1, cv2.LINE_AA)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing == True:
            print('Moving: ',(x,y))
            a, b = x, y
            if a != x & b != y:
                img = img2.copy()
                cv2.line(img,(x2,y2),(x,y),(0,255,0),1, cv2.LINE_AA)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        print('Released: ',(x,y))
        img = img2.copy()
        cv2.line(img,(x2,y2),(x,y),(0,0,255),1, cv2.LINE_AA)


img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
img2 = img.copy()
cv2.namedWindow('Draw')
cv2.setMouseCallback('Draw',draw_shape)


while(True):
    cv2.imshow('Draw',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: It seems great.

Comment: @ausk Are you Silencer ?

Answer (score 2):

You should clear the image (set the background to black) in each state of `event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE`.

You can do this simply by adding `img1[:]=0` just before you drawing a line in `event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE` as:

```
elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
    #drawing = False
    #print('('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
    if drawing == True:
        #print('('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
        a = x
        b = y
        if a != x & b != y:
            img1[:]=0 # <---------------- HERE
            cv2.line(img1,(x1,y1),(x,y),(0,0,255),2)
```

The result would be:

[image]

**UPDATE**

In the case you want to draw multiple image, you should freeze image in each `cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:` event and set it in each `cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE` event as:

```
    global x1,y1,drawing, freeze_image # <------------------------

        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            freeze_image = np.copy(img1) # <------------------------
            drawing = True
            x1,y1 = x,y
            cv2.line(img1,(x1,y1),(x,y),(0,0,255),2)

...

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing == True:
            a = x
            b = y
            if a != x & b != y:
                img1[:]=np.copy(freeze_image) # <------------------------
                cv2.line(img1,(x1,y1),(x,y),(0,0,255),2)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @JeruLuke you said by just doing pass will work. Well that works perfect but now problem is I cannot see line while drawing. And the logic  which Salman mentioned above, in that you can just draw one line cannot many. if you try to to draw second line first one gets disappeared.